# Find all processes emitting a certain biosphere flow in LCA

Tags: brightway

I need to find the processes that use/emit a certain biosphere flow in a LCA. I have seen [here](https://bitbucket.org/cmutel/brightway2-analyzer/src/6a0de92bb7135d72137ba9ec201609d49c40bc51/bw2analyzer/contribution.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#contribution.py-203) that there are some methods that look like what I need but they are commented out. Are they really what I am looking for? If not, is there a way to get this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Naive approach

You can just iterate through all biosphere exchanges in your database:

```
db = Database("ecoinvent 3.2 cutoff")
some_flow = Database("biosphere3").random()
consumers = {
    exc.output 
    for ds in db 
    for exc in ds.biosphere() 
    if exc.input == some_flow
}
```

This is simple and easy to understand, but rather slow.

## Advanced approach

You can do SQL queries on the underlying database:

```
from bw2data.backends.peewee import ExchangeDataset
consumers_fast = [
    get_activity((db.name, obj[0])) for obj in 
    ExchangeDataset.select(ExchangeDataset.output_code).where(
        (ExchangeDataset.input_database == some_flow['database']) &
        (ExchangeDataset.input_code == some_flow['code']) & 
        (ExchangeDataset.output_database == db.name)
    ).distinct().tuples()
]
```

Note: The advanced types of queries will be much easier in the [next Brightway](https://chris.mutel.org/next-brightway.html)

## Examining biosphere matrix in `LCA` object

You can also get this information from a constructed `LCA` object:

```
lca = LCA({db.random(): 1})
lca.lci()
row = lca.biosphere_dict[some_flow]
col_indices = lca.biosphere_matrix[row, :].tocoo()
ra, _, _ = lca.reverse_dict()
consumers_lca = [get_activity(ra[index]) for index in col_indices.col]
consumers_lca
```

If you want to get also the inventory amount from a constructed `LCA` object:

```
lca = LCA({db.random(): 1})
lca.lci()
row = lca.biosphere_dict[some_flow]
col_indices = lca.biosphere_matrix[row, :].tocoo()
ra, _, _ = lca.reverse_dict()
amount_consumers_lca = [lca.inventory[row, index] for index in col_indices.col]
amount_consumers_lca
```

with this you can get the inventory amount from a constructed `LCA` object only for certain processes (`list_of_processes`) using/emitting the biosphere flow (`some_flow`):

```
process_keys = [obj.key for obj in Database("lci_db") if obj["name"] in list_of_processes]
lca = LCA({db.random(): 1})
lca.lci()
row = lca.biosphere_dict[some_flow]
col_indices = lca.biosphere_matrix[row, :].tocoo()
ra, _, _ = lca.reverse_dict()
amount_process_keys_lca = [lca.inventory[row, index] for index in col_indices.col if ra[index] in process_keys]

amount_process_keys_lca
```